# Breathing in Cold Water while doing a Front Crawl

Tags: swimming

I took a pause from swimming, and when I returned, the water temperature is about 11 Celsius. I'm finding that I am running out of breath much faster than usual. I can usually get 3 strokes before taking a breath.

Does breathing while front crawling in cold water require adaptation? For example, if I'm used to 3 strokes per breath, do I need to reduce it to 2, or is it just a matter of form and cold adaptation?

Comment: Are you saying you took time off from training?